# Unable to increase the output volume

Tags: android, pjsip

Tried `endpoint.audDevManager().setOutputVolume(percentage)`, with values ranging between `100-1999`. Unfortunately, it's not resulting in any increase in volume.
[The documentation](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/classpj_1_1AudDevManager.htm#a5075c49613d2777d55b491e699b38c77) suggests that:

> This method is only valid if the device has `PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_VOLUME_SETTING` capability in AudioDevInfo.caps flags.

And I've already ensured that this flag is set. Is there anything else that I need to take care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sauw Ming suggested (over mail) to use [`AudioMedia::adjustRxLevel(float level)`](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/classpj_1_1AudioMedia.htm#acf541502614d847f117817cd12cbcdc4) instead, and that fixed the issue for values of `level` over `3.0`. At least that's when there was perceivable difference in volume.

Answer (score 0):

I also worked with `endpoint.audDevManager().setOutputVolume(percentage)` and it works after the call start.I got the change of volume.Also i used the range 1-100.Please check it with this settings.